# Is it possible to Decorate public properties in another class?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xsd, decorator

I am utilizing a tool Xsd2Code that uses xml schema definition files to generate a DespatchAdvice.designer.cs file containing multiple partial classes.  In my  program I can then conveniently populate relevant data and Serialize the output to xml.

However as is often the case, not all is quite as I'd like it.  I don't require some of the elements that are eventually serialized and not populating the data simply causes them to serialize as empty elements.  The resultant xml must meet stringent criteria set by our customer and these empty elements "break" those criteria.

I have a few choices for getting around this.  I could remove those elements from the original xsd schema files but they are produced by the GS1 standards organization and any updates would break my own customizations or at least require me to reapply them.

Alternatively I could modify the .cs file generated by Xsd2Code, removing those properties not required.  But in a similar vein as above any regeneration of the .cs would trash my modifications.

The approach I'm currently taking is a variation on the latter, decorating the unwanted properties in the .cs file with XmlIgnoreAttribute().  In the following code fragment Manifest has been generated by the tool but must not be serialized in the resulting xml.  All code was auto-generated except for the XmlIgnoreAttribute line.

```
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 3)]
    public DocumentIdentification DocumentIdentification
    {
        get
        {
            return this.documentIdentificationField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.documentIdentificationField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]     // Exclude Manifest
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 4)]
    public Manifest Manifest
    {
        get
        {
            return this.manifestField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.manifestField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Order = 5)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute(IsNullable = false)]
    public List<Scope> BusinessScope
    {
        get
        {
            return this.businessScopeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.businessScopeField = value;
        }
    }
```

So to the crux of my question.  Is there a way I can apply the XmlIgnoreAttribute without modifying the generated DespatchAdvice.designer.cs file (and without having to recode the entire Manifest block in an overload)?

Edit:

These are the options I used when generating the .cs file.  Values I changed from the default value are highlighted.

[image: Xsd2Code options selected]

Comment: Is that other class declared as `partial`?

Comment: Romano, not sure which "other" class you're referring to.  The generated .cs contains multiple partial classes.  Everything else I have free reign over although the only other real class is my Program class (which is not partial, but would that help?)  Sorry, partial classes are a bit of an unknown to me.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates this? Because (usually) setting a property to null would prevent it being serialized at all - see [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jKW2L6). That said, what you're asking can probably be done with [`XmlAttributeOverrides`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @RomanoZumbé, sorry - I missed tagging you in my comment above.

Comment: @CharlesMager , I'm out of the office (and in Australia) so it would take me 24 hours to turn around a mcve, but the code above without my modification produced this output:
    <sh:Manifest />

Comment: @WayneIvory are you setting `Manifest` to null? From memory I think Xsd2Code has an option to initialise everything - perhaps this is enabled? The example I've given you shows `XmlSerializer` pretty much does what you want by default - so it's not clear why this happens.

Comment: @CharlesMager I see now.  No, I'm not setting Manifest to null.  I recall when I started out I was trying to avoid having to set every property explicitly but I pretty much had to do that anyway with the Ignore.  I'll check out your approach tomorrow and come back to you here.

Comment: @CharlesMager Thank you, I've confirmed that setting `Manifest` to null from my main Program achieved the same effect as applying the `XmlIgnoreAttribute()` to the property, i.e. prevented it from being serialized.  Although not directly addressing the Title (which is probably more my fault than yours) if you want to submit this as an answer I'm happy to accept it.  I may raise a related question later once I can formulate it properly in my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xsd2Code has an option to initialise all fields, so I suspect what happens here is that a 'default' `Manifest` is created and that's what your seeing when you serialize the object graph.

The `XmlSerializer` behaviour is to omit elements that are `null` unless the `XmlElement` attribute has the [`IsNullable` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.isnullable(v=vs.110).aspx) set to `true`. In that case it would serialize an empty element with an `xsi:nil="true"` attribute.

So, rather than trying to add or override the attributes (which you can achieve using [`XmlAttributeOverrides`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides(v=vs.110).aspx)), I'd suggest you just set the elements you want to omit to `null`.

Comment: I edited my original post to include the Xsd2Code options I used.  Can you please indicate which option you are referring to that will "initialise all fields" - none of them seem to have that exact description.

Comment: @WayneIvory My guess is `EnableInitializeFields = True` (the second property on your screenshot). I think this results in e.g. `Manifest = new Manifest();` being generated in the constructor. This is often useful as you can just set properties without worrying about null references.